# OpenCV small screen showing delay?

Tags: c++, opencv, delay

I am using OpenCV to write an app (in C++ on Windows 7) that uses the cv.camshift() function to track an object on the screen. I noticed that the my camera window (my application window showing what the camera sees) has a little delay with respect to very rapid motions. The delay seems to be about 0.1 seconds - very small, but noticable. I am developing an application that is very sensitive to these delays. In order to rule out my coding error, I tried to use one of the OpenCV sample video apps that shows what the camera sees on the screen and it also had this tiny delay. Interestingly, when I look at what my camera sees through Skype, there seems to be virtually no delay at all. Is there anything I can do to make OpenCV operate faster to get rid of this tiny delay?

Answer (score 1):

CamShift detects motion using meanShift - the mean motion of the object center.  This has to be calculated over more than one frame.  For a frame rate of 30 Hz, a depth of 3 frames would be 0.1 seconds.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for explaining! So I will need to implement a different technique - one that doesn't involve taking the mean. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing that surprises me, though, is that when I run the camera.py demo that was packaged with the OpenCV superpack, and use it to just see the output of the camera, I can actually observe that when I quickly move an object in the field of view, there is a tiny delay as well. In this case, no camshifting is done. So maybe there is more to the delay than calculating over multiple frames. Please, let me know if you think this is wrong.

Comment: To add to this discussion after doing more research - it turns out that the delay is intrinsic to the camera - computer latency in communication. The only way to get rid of it is getting a more professional camera that has lower latency. We ended up going with PointGrey camera whose latency is very small. So this is not a software issue, but a hardware issue.